# How to change background color of ImageButton in android

Tags: android, android-button

I have a search button and I want the background color to be a light blue. Here is my `ImageButton`

```
<ImageButton
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_search"
    android:background="@android:color/searchBlue"/>
```

I want the background color to be a light blue. But `@android:color/searchBlue` is highlighted red. Here is my `colors.xml` file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <color name="loomiusBlue">#00A6FF</color>
    <color name="white">#FFFFFF</color>
    <color name="headBlue">#2196F3</color>
    <color name="searchBlue">#B3E5FC</color>
</resources>
```

Comment: is searchBlue defined by yourself in a color.xml ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is wrong, because this searches for this color resource in the core android resources, not your local resources:

```
android:background="@android:color/searchBlue"
```

This should work, if this color exists in your color.xml:

```
android:background="@color/searchBlue"
```

Answer (score 1):

If the color `searchBlue` is defined by Yourself inside a `color.xml`, You have to use

```
android:background="@color/searchBlue"
```

instead. `@android` will refere to android resources and not your resources.